# PHP cURL - how to emulate exactly same request like user?

Tags: php, curl, scraper

I am trying to make a website scraper, but the website is acting diferrently, than normal request via browser.

How can i make perfect cURL reguest, that the website will not filter it and block it?

Any help would be appriciated.

```
$curl_handle = curl_init ("***");
$header = array();
$header[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0";
$header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: cs,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: utf-8";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Host: ****";


curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
```

This is, what i got so far, but it is still getting blocked.

Comment: You should provide the code that your are using now.

Comment: I just edited the post, so feel free to help.

Comment: How the website is acting,what is your code and what you want to achieve?

Comment: When i request the page via browser, the response is ok, but when i request via cURL, it redirects me to the homepage, so i think, it is kind of blocking mine scraper.

Comment: did you printed the result ? @TadeášJílek

Comment: Yes, the result is redirect.

Comment: @TadeášJílek please post the url

Comment: Why not simply open up your chrome, and visit the website with console tools open and capture the request and response headers right there?

Comment: Yeah, i did this, those headers are headers, what i have caught like this.

Comment: @TadeášJílek please post the url

Answer (score 0):

The following CURL options might help:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```